# Why Riemann sum is convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Why $\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$ is convergent? I don't understand how we can prove that is bounded and monotone...

For instance: $f:R\rightarrow R,\:\:f=\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}$, and the Riemann sum is: $a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\sum _{k=1}^n\:\left(\frac{n+k}{n^2+k^2}\right)$, why $a_n$ is convergent?

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Have you noticed that you didn't even hint what $\;f\;$ is ...?? As it is, the question makes not much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf\Bigl(\frac kn\Bigr)=\int_0^1f(x)\,dx.
$$
Depending on the definition of Riemann integral you are using, this is either an immediate consequence of the definition or a theorem.

If $f$ is bounded, say $|f(x)|\le M$, then
$$
\Bigl|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf\Bigl(\frac kn\Bigr)\Bigr|\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nM=M
$$
and the Riemann sums are also bounded. However, even if $f$ is Riemann integrable, the Riemann sums may not be monotone.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f'$ is bounded by some $M$, you get
$$\left|\int _{\frac{k-1}n}^{\frac kn} f(t) dt - 
\frac 1n f\left( \frac kn \right)\right|
=\left| \int _{\frac{k-1}n}^{\frac kn} \left[f(t) 
- f\left( \frac kn \right)\right]dt\right|
\le  \int _{\frac{k-1}n}^{\frac kn} 
\left| f(t) - f\left( \frac kn \right) \right|dt
\\ \le  M\int _{\frac{k-1}n}^{\frac kn} \left(\frac kn - t\right) dt
= \frac M{2n^2}
$$
From this you get that the sum converges.

Comment: and always Riemann sum is convergent?

Comment: when $f'$ is bounded, it is always convergent indeed.